# Batch commands to open .bat file in another program

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm having some trouble with this part of the batch code:

```
SET /P C="Would You Like To EDIT Shows or EXIT? |"

IF /I "%C%" EQU "Edit" START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "G:\Backup\Backup Folder 2\Batch Commands\Shows.bat"

IF /I "%C%" EQU "Exit" GOTO :Exit
```

The current file is named Shows.bat and I want to give the option to open it with notepad++ if I say "Edit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `start`, the command assumes that the first thing it finds in quotes is supposed to be the window title. You can put `""` after start to make it work the way you were expecting.

```
@echo off
set /p c="Would you like to EDIT shows or EXIT? |"
if /i "%c%" equ "Edit" start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "G:\Backup\Backup Folder 2\Batch Commands\Shows.bat"
if /i "%c%" equ "Exit" goto exit
```

Comment: Sure thing. If I gave you the answer you were looking for, click the check next to my answer.